# CS50 pset7 movies Q13

Tags: sql, cs50

For the pset7 Q13 problem, my SQL code is returning back the error:

```
Result: ambiguous column name: id
At line 1:
```

This shouldnt be the case because there is a column name that is "id."

Q13:
In 13.sql, write a SQL query to list the names of all people who starred in a movie in which Kevin Bacon also starred.

- Your query should output a table with a single column for the name of each person.
- There may be multiple people named Kevin Bacon in the database. Be sure to only select the Kevin Bacon born in 1958.
- Kevin Bacon himself should not be included in the resulting list.

`SELECT name FROM people, stars WHERE people.id = stars.person_id AND stars.movie_id IN (SELECT id FROM movies, stars, people WHERE movies.id = stars.movie_id AND stars.person_id = people.id AND name = "Kevin Bacon" AND birth = 1958);`

UPDATED:

`SELECT name FROM people, stars WHERE people.id = stars.person_id AND stars.movie_id IN (SELECT movies.id FROM movies, stars, people WHERE movies.id = stars.movie_id AND stars.person_id = people.id AND name = "Kevin Bacon" AND birth = 1958) AND name != "Kevin Bacon";`

Comment: Check out your movies, stars and people tables. You must have a column named "id" in at least 2 of those tables. Change "select id" to "select tableyouwant.id.

Comment: I updated it to include the table I wanted, but now the result is 183 people when it should just be 176. I already removed all Kevin Bacons.

Comment: is it 183 distinct people? select distinct name from...